# react-native-maps geolocation.watchPosition() never updates

Tags: geolocation, react-native-maps

I have been trying for hours now to get geolocation.watchPosition() to actually trigger beyond the initial first componentDidMount() trigger.  I have read every guide I can find on this and as far as I can see, I am doing everything people suggest.

Here is the code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
        (position) => {
            let region = {
                latitude:       position.coords.latitude,
                longitude:      position.coords.longitude,
                latitudeDelta:  0.02500,
                longitudeDelta: 0.01000,
                enableHighAccuracy: true
            }
            this.state.currentLatitude = region.latitude;
            this.state.currentLongitude = region.longitude;
            console.log("WatchPosition Triggered");
            this.onRegionChangeComplete(region, region.latitude, region.longitude);
        },
        (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 5000, maximumAge: 4000, distanceFilter: 1, useSignificantChanges: false },
    );
}

onRegionChangeComplete(region, lastLat, lastLong) {
    this.setState({
        mapRegion: region,
        lastLat: lastLat || this.state.lastLat,
        lastLong: lastLong || this.state.lastLong
    });
}
```

I have that console.log in there so I can see every time this function actually triggers in the app, and it just doesn't beyond the first instance of the map screen loading.   I have tried walking around, confirming that my location is tracking perfectly, but this function never, ever triggers again.

Have I missed something?   I can't find anything different in any example.

Please help if you can, I am pouring hours into this problem.